# Youtube search API always consuming 100 units

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, rate-limiting

I use the Youtube V3 Search API to get only 1 video ID:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=skating&fields=items%2Fid%2FvideoId&key=my-key
```

The result of this call is:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": {
                "videoId": "rYEDA3JcQqw"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that this is costing me 100 units!
Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the videoId, don't use the search API, but the videos API instead

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=u6ZSgqS37kM&maxResults=1&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

This costs only 3 units instead of 100.

If you really want to search, there is no way to go under 100 units, that's the normal quota for search. However, you can set maxResults to 50, so you will get 50 results for the same 100 units.

You can use the quota calculator to find out the exact numbers: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the ID, so I really need to search. I have BTW just abandoned a side project because of this ridiculous request costs.

Comment: One possible solution I use is to open a youtube page with the search from your page and scraping the results page. It has many drawbacks though, on the first place it's quite complicated to put together.

Comment: It's such a high cost. Truly ridiculous.

Comment: Agreed, I had to abandon it in a project as well as the limit makes the API useless.